# Making requests to telegram's BotFather for bots factory

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to make something like telegram bots factory, but can't find any ways how to make requests to @BotFather and get tokens.

There is nothing in telegram API documentation. Is it possible?

Workflow should look like:
1) Users input Telegram Bot name
2) Backend makes request to BotFather, creates new bot and saves token in database.
3) User see the result (OK/Can't create).

Are there any working solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Bots can't talk to each other and there is no way you can obtain a token from BotFather using Telegram API. You need to ask your users to create a bot and give you their token.